Is there a way to have a non historical streaming dataset in Power BI, and still use a custom visual on a dashboard
This is a combo problem of custom-visuals and streaming datasets.
I've made a custom Power BI visual. The main purpose of it was to showcase real-time data using a streaming push dataset.
Without activating the "historical data" option when making the streaming dataset, you can't make a report on it. When the "historical data" option is off, you can only use the dataset on a dashboard tile.
Now the dashboard tile offers really dumb basic charts. I see no option to add a custom visual here.
So I'm stuck in a loop now. In order to have my custom visual on a dashboard, I need to make a report, add the visual there, then pin that visual to a dashboard. But in order to do that, I need to activate "historical data," which is not preferred.
The other option that Power BI offers is to go to the dashboard, add a tile, and select the streaming dataset, but that route doesn't even offer me an option to insert a custom visual
Any workarounds, or am I missing something?
Everything I've tried is listed in the details
